# add legend with the exact value of a mean line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have made a plot using matplotlib library, which depicts two histograms and the mean lines. I think that the plot would be more clear if I add the legend. I want to create a legend, which says what exact values have this two mean lines. Below I attache my code and the plot which I generated and the picture which shows what I want to achieve (it is picture where I added the legend using powerpoint):

```
def setPlot(data, mycolor, myalpha, mylinestyle):
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=12)
    plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=12)
    plt.xlabel("Incomes")
    plt.hist(data, bins=50, color= mycolor, alpha=myalpha)
    plt.axvline(numpy.mean(data), color=mycolor, linestyle=mylinestyle, linewidth=1.5)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

-----------SOLUTION--------

Thanks to the great advises from **wwii** and **tom** I was able to implement the solution to my idea. I have tried to concatenate both suggestions, and this is what I obtained:

```
def setPlot(data, mycolor, myalpha, mylinestyle):
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=12)
    plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=12)
    plt.xlabel("Incomes")
    plt.hist(data, bins=50, color= mycolor, alpha=myalpha)
    plt.axvline(numpy.mean(data), color=mycolor, linestyle=mylinestyle, linewidth=1.5, label=str(numpy.mean(data)))
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.show()
```

And the example of my generated plot:
[image]

Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Did you look through the [matplotlib Gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html)?

Comment: @wwii Thank, I will definitely check it and maybe I will find something helpful!

Comment: Assign the ```Line2D``` object that is returned by ```axvline``` to a name/variable. then use that as an argument to ```legend``` - like in this [example from the gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/legend_demo2.html#pylab-examples-example-code-legend-demo2-py).  If you figure it out, feel free to answer your own question with the solution.

Comment: @wwii Many thanks for your help! I have learned how to do that and improved my plot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to give you `axvline` a `label`, then call `plt.legend` after plotting both your histograms. Like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def setPlot(data, mycolor, myalpha, mylinestyle):
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=12)
    plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=12)
    plt.xlabel("Incomes")
    plt.hist(data, bins=50, color= mycolor, alpha=myalpha)
    plt.axvline(numpy.mean(data), color=mycolor, linestyle=mylinestyle,
                linewidth=1.5,label='{:5.0f}'.format(numpy.mean(data)))

setPlot(numpy.random.rand(100)*30000.,'r',0.5,'--')
setPlot(numpy.random.rand(100)*20000.,'b',0.5,'-')

plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.savefig('myfig.png')
```

[image]